# Rails 4: User Login for SubDomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, devise

I am creating a rails application that allows a user to sign up and create subdomains (communities). The user becomes the admin of each subdomain they create. They should be able to invite users to signup/login into each subdomain.

I don't want to share session across several subdomains in rails. Each subdomain should be it's on echo system control by the user who created it.

How can I accomplish this with Devise?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following this guide:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain